# How can I stop my JQuery Menu going off the screen for larger menus?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

I've got a JQuery menu which I need to always stay visible on the screen at all times. So if the child menu would overlap the bottom of the window it should shift "up".

e.g.[image]

It seems to work fine for smaller menus (e.g 5 items or less), but weirdly bigger ones seem to never shift up.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tAH6a/8/)- compare Menu Items C>1E to C>1F (You might need to resize your window so that they actually overlap the bottom)

i.e.
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 250px;">
          <ul id="filter-menu-button-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span>B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open"></span>C</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1A</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">1B</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#">1C</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#">1D</a></li> 
                  <li><a href="#">1E</a>
                      <ul>
                  <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">1</a></li>
                      <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">2</a></li>
                      <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">3</a></li>
                      <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">4</a></li>
                          <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                        <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">6</a></li>

                      </ul>
                  </li> 
                  <li><a href="#">1F</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                        <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                        <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                        <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                        <li><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span><a href="#">5</a></li>                   
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
    "position": { my: "right top", at: "left top" }
});
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening? Is it a bug in JQuery UI? Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the collision options for [.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/tAH6a/17/)**

```
$('#filter-menu-button-menu').menu({
    "position": {
        my: "right top",
        at: "left top",
        collision: 'flipfit'
    }
});
```

> "flipfit": First applies the flip logic, placing the element on
>   whichever side allows more of the element to be visible. Then the fit
>   logic is applied to ensure as much of the element is visible as
>   possible.

Comment: This is literally the perfect solution. Thank you so much!